# Trouble with mtgox's withdraw bitcoins api call

Tags: mtgox, api, withdrawal

I have been trying to transfer bitcoins via mtgox's withdraw bitcoin api call with this http address

https://data.mtgox.com/api/1/generic/bitcoin/send_simple

and when I log the response to console I get

```
{ result: 'success',
  return: { trx: 'a748ee68583a1cedbdde694a5716909cad8feea1545e946145f48f95ced15037' } }
```

yet the number of bitcoins in my account remains unchanged.

What could possibly be causing this?

and I'm positive my api key has the correct permissions (unless it's merchant)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was having had to do with formatting. In the [api documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Withdraw_bitcoins) there is an `amount_int` param which needs to be passed with the `http` request. I had forgotten that mtgox requires anything with `_int` postfixing to be in the form `amount * 10 ^ 8`

so for example if you were trying to send 0.01 bitcoins for the `amount_int` field you would put

```
0.01 * 10 ^ 8 = 1000000
```